# How to Convert Complex XML to Object with List and not an Array?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe

I've XML which I'm converting to c# object

First I created a schema file and then by xsd.exe  I've converted it to object.

The issue is that all complex elements (appears inside the XML several times are converted to array and actually i want it to be converted to list.

Any way to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually xsd.exe doesn't have such option. But you can generate classes using [Svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)  in which you can specify collection type using `/collectionType:<type>` option.